# shifting chars in C with modulus, outputting to file produces unsupported file format on one input, txt file on other input

Tags: c, linux, encryption, file-io, io

Here's a function I wrote in C, it's run with linux console 'cat' command and you pass a txt file into it then tell the function whether you want 'encode' or 'decode' followed by a password.. it produces an 'encrypted' file which can only (almost) be decrypted by running the program again with the encrypted file as input and decode + correct password as arguments...

you can run this code through command console on linux machine like so

```
cat your_txt_file | ./ThisProgram encode password > encoded_file

cat encoded_file | ./ThisProgram decode password > decoded_file
```

this 'SHOULD and sometimes' does, produce two txt files, encoded_file / decoded_file.

you should see no difference between your_txt_file and decoded_file

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buffer;
    char *pw = argv[2];
    int ptrpw = 0;
    int code = 0;


    if (strcmp(argv[1], "encode") == 0) {
        code=  cumSumCrypt(pw, code);

        while ( scanf("%c", &buffer) != EOF ) {
            printf("%c", (((int)buffer + code) % 256));
        }
    }



    if (strcmp(argv[1], "decode") == 0) {
        code= cumSumCrypt(pw, code);

        while ( scanf("%c", &buffer) != EOF ) {
            printf("%c", (256 + ((int)buffer - code)) % 256);

        }
    }

    return 0;
}


int cumSumCrypt(char *pw, int sum){
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < sizeof pw; i++){
        sum +=(int) pw[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

the problem is that sometimes when I run the program, the intermediary file it produces.. the encrypted one is sometimes not a txt file, but it can still be passed through the decryption and the final output is fine.. so the program fulfilled  it's purpose, but I've asked around university, looked on google etc and can't find anyone who can explain the strange behaviour.

Whether or not the encrypted file it produces can be opened in .txt depends on what password you give to it, I've found giving it 'hl' as a pw makes the encrypted file ineligible, but can still be opened which is WAI, but 'hello' as a pw makes a file that I can't open... but can still pass through 'cat' in the console and decrypt it without error.

The program itself does a Caeser shift on every character in the input file and the size of the shift is a sum of the characters of your password, with modulo 256 after you've added the txt file's character to the sum.

Comment: When you say you can't open the file, you mean you can't say `cat -v fileName`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nominally, a text file must end with a newline.  Your program does not ensure that there is a newline at the end of the file, so it does not always generate a text file.  Indeed, it probably does so one time in 256 (or maybe 255; what do you do about null bytes?).  Most Unix programs aren't that fussy about the last line, but some are.

So, if that's the definition of a text file, it isn't very surprising that you don't produce one.

In any case, the intermediate file is likely to contain a whole bunch of characters that make it look unlike a text file — depending on the password, of course.  You use the password to generate a value for a Caesar shift.  This means that most of your alphabetic characters are going to be shifted to a non-alphabetic position.  This is fairly normal for an encryption program; it produces pseudo-random gibberish as output, and regenerates the original from it.  If you prefer, you can arrange to provide a mapping between alphabetic or alphanumeric characters only, leaving punctuation and white space unmapped.  You'd have to look up how to generate such codes, but it can surely be done, leaving you with a text file output for a text file input.

```
$ cat input
This is the input data for the encryption program.
It consists of two shortish lines.
$ edc encode password < input > output
$ odx output
0x0000: C7 DB DC E6 93 DC E6 93 E7 DB D8 93 DC E1 E3 E8   ................
0x0010: E7 93 D7 D4 E7 D4 93 D9 E2 E5 93 E7 DB D8 93 D8   ................
0x0020: E1 D6 E5 EC E3 E7 DC E2 E1 93 E3 E5 E2 DA E5 D4   ................
0x0030: E0 A1 7D BC E7 93 D6 E2 E1 E6 DC E6 E7 E6 93 E2   ..}.............
0x0040: D9 93 E7 EA E2 93 E6 DB E2 E5 E7 DC E6 DB 93 DF   ................
0x0050: DC E1 D8 E6 A1 7D                                 .....}
0x0056:
$ edc decode password < output > copy
$ cmp input copy
$ edc encode AAAA < input > output.AAAA
$ odx output.AAAA
0x0000: 58 6C 6D 77 24 6D 77 24 78 6C 69 24 6D 72 74 79   Xlmw$mw$xli$mrty
0x0010: 78 24 68 65 78 65 24 6A 73 76 24 78 6C 69 24 69   x$hexe$jsv$xli$i
0x0020: 72 67 76 7D 74 78 6D 73 72 24 74 76 73 6B 76 65   rgv}txmsr$tvskve
0x0030: 71 32 0E 4D 78 24 67 73 72 77 6D 77 78 77 24 73   q2.Mx$gsrwmwxw$s
0x0040: 6A 24 78 7B 73 24 77 6C 73 76 78 6D 77 6C 24 70   j$x{s$wlsvxmwl$p
0x0050: 6D 72 69 77 32 0E                                 mriw2.
0x0056:
$ file output.AAAA
output.AAAA: data
$ edc decode AAAA < output.AAAA > copy.AAAA
$ cmp input copy.AAAA
$
```

---

Your `cumSumCrypt()` function has problems:

```
int cumSumCrypt(char *pw, int sum){
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < sizeof pw; i++){
        sum +=(int) pw[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

The `sizeof` means you use either 4 or 8 bytes of the password, which bodes ill if the password string is not that long.  You probably had `strlen(pw)` in mind.

Using `scanf()` and `printf()` to read single characters is a bit of overkill; the functions `getchar()` and `putchar()` would handle that as neatly.

Your code should check that you were provided at least two command line arguments (or exactly two command line arguments) before using them.  Run with zero or one argument, your code will crash.

Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int cumSumCrypt(char *pw);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int c;
    int code;

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s {encode|decode} password\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    code = cumSumCrypt(argv[2]);

    if (strcmp(argv[1], "encode") == 0)
    {
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
            putchar((c + code) % 256);
    }

    if (strcmp(argv[1], "decode") == 0)
    {
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
            putchar((256 + (c - code)) % 256);
    }

    return 0;
}

int cumSumCrypt(char *pw)
{
    size_t sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(pw); i++)
        sum += pw[i];
    return sum % 256;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much!
I didn't know files had to end with a newline, that makes sense though how it would jumble up the formatting, but could still be decoded later, highly appreciate providing me with correct solution!!

I also didn't know about the difference of strlen and sizeof, but now that you pointed out there is one and that 1 is calculated at compile time.. the other at runtime is good to know.

C is so much more perplexing than Java I must say!

This is my first program in C lol